# INTERSECT on a particular column or excluding a column

Tags: sql

Been a while since i've played in the SQL world and I could use a hand trying to solve this one as I haven't been able to work out how to do it yet.

I have a query where I am joining a lot of results using `UNION` and removing using `INTERSECT` such as:

```
(query 1
UNION
query 2
UNION 
query 3)
INTERSECT
query 4
```

My problem is that I have a computed column in each of the queries 1-3 that denotes which query they came from.

i.e.

```
col 1 | col 2 | col3 ....
 q1   |   A   |  B   ....
 q2   |   A   |  D   ....
 q3   |   E   |  D   ....
```

The union of these is fine, but when I want to intersect it with another query I cannot seem to find a way to ignore that column.

SO my question is: **How can I ignore a column when doing an intersect, or intersect only on a specified column?**

NOTE: I could incorporate q4 into each of the other queries but that seems like a lot of unnecessary duplication.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INNER JOIN` instead of `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT q.col1 AS uQ, x.col1 AS iQ, q.col2, q.col3
FROM
(
 SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('q1', 'A', 'B')) q(col1, col2, col3)
 UNION
 SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('q2', 'A', 'D')) q(col1, col2, col3)
 UNION 
 SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('q3', 'E', 'D')) q(col1, col2, col3)
) AS q(col1, col2, col3)
INNER JOIN (VALUES ('q4', 'E', 'D')) AS x(col1, col2, col3) 
ON q.col2 = x.col2 AND q.col3 = x.col3
```

Simply include in the `ON` clause of the `INNER JOIN` all columns involved in the  intersection.

Output from above query is:

```
uQ  iQ  col2  col3
===================
q3  q4  E     D
```

Comment: In my example above I simplified the queries for readability, but the queries contain various joins, Where clauses and sub queries. and if i understand correct, you cant really use a join after the WHERE?

Comment: @Calum You can try substituting all queries of the `UNION` operation with your actual queries. The result of this `UNION` operation is just a derived table with `q(col1, col2, col3)` as an alias. You can then perform an `INNER JOIN` all the same.

Comment: thanks for the advise, I implemented it using the INNER JOIN method, and it works, but has the readability has suffered as a result. So for the sack of a few repeated lines, I will probably stick with the better readability